# How to trace stepDefinition class file from Package Name provided in Runner class in existing BDD Cucumber framework

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber, bdd

I just moved in to a new Project in BDD Cucumber. The Problem which I am facing is:

I want to trace the StepDefinition script which is backend code for feature file.
At the moment we mention only package name in runner class under glue.

How to trace that this feature is written in which StepDefinition file among 40 to 50 StepDefinition files under same (StepDefinition) package?

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Since your question doesn't mention which programming language you use, I do not know which tools are available.

If you are using a JVM language, I'd recommend using IntelliJ IDE with the Cucumber for Java plugin. This allows you to click on the step in the feature file and go to the corresponding step definition, the same way you can navigate to a method implementation from the call site.

UPDATE: If you are using Eclipse (as per user's comment below), the Cucumber plugin for Eclipse should also offer this functionality (more info [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse/issues/204).

Your question implies that a particular feature is implemented in a particular step definition file. This is actually considered an anti-pattern in Cucumber: [see the Cucumber docs on anti-patterns](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/anti-patterns/)

In order to be able to find your step definitions, it is recommend to group them "in a meaningful way". What is "meaningful" will depend on your context.
For example, my current team has a service that aggregates data from several other backend services with their own specific domain/domain objects; we have grouped our step definitions according to the underlying services/domains.
Let's say the service aggregates information about orders; we have the following step definition files:

- interaction with our own system (aggregator)
- getting (or mocking/stubbing) orders from the order system
- getting information about the product in the order from the product service
- getting information about shipment of the order from logistical service
  etc.

By ordering your step definitions in a way that is meaningful to you & your team, it will be easier for everyone to find the step definitions / know where to add new ones, etc.

Finally, have you spoken with your team about how the step definitions are grouped and why? That should help you understand. (sometimes the problem isn't a technical one to be solved with tool, but rather a communication problem that should be solved by talking to each other)

Comment: let me correct : i am using eclipse here( cucumber with java ):What i want to do ? I want to know where is my step definition file for a given feature file .for example lets say Then user clicks on submit .Now i want to see where the code is written for this step..?

Comment: Idk how this works in Eclipse ( I haven't used it in years). But iirc there is an Eclipse plugin for Cucumber too, which should let you do the same. If not, you could search the project for (part of) the string from the step to find the step definition. I really do recommend structuring your step definitions in a meaningful way, to help you and your team know where to locate / update / add step definitions.

Comment: @ami Looks like this should work in the Cucumber plugin for Eclipse, by pressing F3 or ctrl+click. You may have to update your plugin / remove other (conflicting) plugins to get it to work: More information here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse/issues/204

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake..i uninstalled natural and bdd plugin accidentally...and didn't figure out now after reinstalling it is working fine.